# vf_codecview.c printing motion vectors in 'future' only

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to understand the way ffmpeg draws motion vectors.

I went through the `vf_codecview.c` file and saw the function [`draw_arrow`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/vf__codecview_8c_source.html#l00209) which takes only those vectors where `source > 0` implying only those from the future.

Does anyone know why is this? And what's the use of computing past and future, if ffmpeg through this file takes only the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't appear to be the case

`source` can take on either positive or negative value.

```
/**
 * Where the current macroblock comes from; negative value when it comes
 * from the past, positive value when it comes from the future.
 * XXX: set exact relative ref frame reference instead of a +/- 1 "direction".
 */
int32_t source;
```

In the call you linked to, we have

```
if ((direction == 0 && (s->mv & MV_P_FOR)  && frame->pict_type == AV_PICTURE_TYPE_P) ||
    (direction == 0 && (s->mv & MV_B_FOR)  && frame->pict_type == AV_PICTURE_TYPE_B) ||
    (direction == 1 && (s->mv & MV_B_BACK) && frame->pict_type == AV_PICTURE_TYPE_B))
    draw_arrow(frame->data[0], mv->dst_x, mv->dst_y, mv->src_x, mv->src_y,
              frame->width, frame->height, frame->linesize[0],
              100, 0, mv->source > 0);
```

If the macroblock is predicted from a past frame, the last expression evaluates to and is passed as `0`, else `1`.

The conditional clearly allows for both past- and future- predicted macroblocks.

P.S. you are looking at the source for ver `2.5`, which is very old, at this point. Current version is at https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/vf__codecview_8c_source.html#l00256

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.